# PHP failed attempts to log in record in a txt file

Tags: php

Basically to keep it short I have an assignment for college where I have to make a few scripts.

In one of these I have to make a scripts that records when data is entered wrong in a log in form. So it will take the users IP address and place it into a text file followed by the time, date, error name (e.g. wrong username and password, wrong name, w.e.), error page and attempts made.

I have figured out: 
how to get the users ip
how to get the time and date
how to record the attempts

Now, what I want to do: I want the script to search for the users IP address and if this IP address has already been recorded for a failed attempt, instead of making a new record I want it to just add 1 to the attempts made to that IP address, update the time and date. Only in the case that this IP address has not been recorded a new record should be created.

```
if IP ALREADY EXISTS{
FIND AMOUNT OF ATTEMPTS
attempts++;

} 

else{
   ADD IP;
   ADD TIME;
   ADD DATE;
   ADD REASON;
   attempt=1;
}
```

this is what i have so far:

```
<?php
$time = date("h:i:sa");
$date = date("d/m/y");
$error = "Incorrect Data Entered";
$attempts = 0;
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
$myFile = "errorLog.txt"; 
$file = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$searchfor = "$ip";

// the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
$contents = file_get_contents($myFile);
// escape special characters in the query
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '$ip');
// finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
// search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "Found matches:\n";
   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
else{
  $attempts = 1;                
  $stringData = "$ip, $time, $date, $error, $attempts\n";
  fwrite($file, $stringData);
  fclose($file);
}
?>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged C++? It has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: it would be much easier with a db than a flat file

Comment: i'm using c++ to do this, if it has nothing to do with c++ i am sorry, also i know it is easier to do with DB but the criteria asks for a file format, i know how to do this with mysql db :|

Comment: If you are using C++ then why is it tagged as PHP?

Comment: my bad, took the c++ off, got confused, really sorry

Comment: c++ and php are different languages. Some PHP syntax might resemble C, but...

Comment: IP does not  equal user, many people share the same IP

Comment: Then I suggest, you organize the file like a `CSV` file. But searching and editing a file will require opening and closing the file multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply append to the same text file over and over then if you really want to add up the number of attempts by each individual user, then your going to need to rewrite the full txt file as far as I'm aware.
If you want to make it easier for yourself then you can write your txt file in such a way that you can easily obtain the values you need out of it, such as the ip address.

You could write each line like:

```
IPADDRESS,ERROR CODE,ATTEMPTS /n
```

Then when you want to change that line you'll need to keep a record of which line it is. A loop will be required to parse your txt file. 
So the way I would attempt it would be:

Store text from file into a variable.

Use the explode() function to create an array of records. ( Like a row in a database ). I would use it like `$rows = explode("/n" , $txt);`

Loop through the rows. I would probably use `foreach( $rows as $row)` for this.

Keep track of the row number. So create a variable for it and iterate it.

Use the `explode()` function again to create a `list($ip, $err, $attempts)` by doing: `list($ip, $err, $attempts) = explode("," , $row);`

Now use normal php if() function to check to see if the two ips match, if the error codes are the same.

If they do, you can do `$attempts++`. Now the tricky/essential part.

You will need to create a string up to but NOT including that row and place it into a variable call it something like `$firstpart`.

You will also need to do the same for the rows after the affect row. eg `$lastpart`

Now create a new string for your affected row. Easily done: `$str = $ip . "," . $err . "," . $attempts;`

Finally, write your txt file using the variables, in the order: `$firstpart, $str, $lastpart.`

Not sure if this will work, not sure how practical this is, but at the very least I hope it helps you to get some sort of brainwave for how to approach your problem.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code formatting Dragon, did this on my phone, wouldn't let me do it.